# Looking for a way to record video from an iphone embedded within a web browser and saved to a server

Tags: iphone, flash, webcam, red5

Ok, so I'm working on a project that will allow users to record themselves within a browser and have the video save to the server for later watching.

Right now I have an implementation where I'm using Red5 server with Red5 Recorder and that is working fine, but I'm wondering how exactly you could go about this on an iphone as that is expected to be a large user base.

As far as my research has shown there is no universal way to gather this video within the browser as there is no HTML5 solution and Flash seems to be by far the best way to record webcam to a server.

So what I'm wondering is has anybody encountered this issue and found a solution, whether it be for Iphone only, or a universal solution that would work across all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the only way to accomplish this on the iPhone would be to write a native application. The web browser doesn't give access to the camera, and it doesn't support Flash, Java etc.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, you can use an <input> tag for iOS6 and iOS7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783092/video-recording-web-app/19806951