# Video recording web app

Tags: html, flash, video-streaming, html5-video, red5

I have a website requirement , users can able to record video (with sound) and upload to server.
First i think about flash and red5(media server) but found that flash does not support IPAD or iphone.
Now am think about HTML5 video recording, but somebody told me that html5 video recording still in beta and not stable and it does not support all browsers.

Please advice which is best , help is highly appreciable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To upload a video from an iPhone to a web server, you can use an `<input>` tag. This will prompt the user to record a video which will then be selected as the file to upload.

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="file" name="video_file" accept="video/*" capture />
```

Wrap this in  and you can change the appearance of the  tag to look more like a video recording button.

Answer (score 0):

There's simply no way as of now to do video recording through mobile browser. Potential solution is

1. Direct mobile browser user to appstore/google play and encourage to download a dedicated app (downside - you have to write it ;)
2. Allow for file upload from mobile device (user uploads prerecorded video). File uploads are supported from IOS6 only. Not sure about Android.
3. Use flash where possible (a challenge in itself).

Hint: would I accept such requirement as a contractor/agency etc? Nooo! Never ;)

Comment: I have to agree with point 1 at least, but I suppose you could write a web/native hybrid app that might not take a lot of time develop

Comment: The big question is would anybody like to be redirected to app download in order to perform a single action on a website (record video). I quietly hope that the braindead trend of redirecting users from websites to silly apps that do silly things in a silly way is becoming thing in a past these days.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate responce, but i found some html5 recording is working on IOS6 safari and chrome on android phones??